# Postgres - Create user that can read future views

Tags: postgresql, authentication, view, roles

I need to create a new user on postgres "dev-api"

```
CREATE USER "dev-api" WITH PASSWORD 'mypassword123';
```

I want to provide read access to future views, how i can to that?
This user can not read tables, can not create objects or insert/delete/update tables,
he just can read views,

any idea?

Comment: There is [ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) but it does not distinguish tables from views. Nor does [GRANT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html), so I don't see this as possible.

Comment: Perhaps with an event trigger.